# How can I get VSTS working with private nuget repos which require credentials?

Tags: telerik, continuous-integration, nuget, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up a CI/CD system and the company has chosen Visual Studio Team Services.

Everything was going well until I noticed my build failing here:

> Error:
> d:\a_tasks\NuGetInstaller_333b11bd-d341-40d9-afcf-b32d5ce6f23b\0.2.31\node_modules\nuget-task-common\NuGet\3.3.0\NuGet.exe
> failed with return code: 1
>
> Packages failed to install

The software project uses Telerik DLL's that are retrieved from a private Telerik nuget repo - which requires credentials to access.

Now obviously there must be a way to tell VSTS in the 'Nuget Restore' build step but I can't find anything online other than create our own hosted company Repo and tell VSTS about it - which isn't helpful because I don't want to host Telerik's own DLL's.

Is there any way to do this or should I move to TeamCity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version (`2.*`) of the NuGet task supports both privately NuGet feeds and specifying the credentials for it (see screenshot). You simply need to leverage a NuGet configuration file to achieve this. Read [Configure NuGet behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior) for more details.

Also note that if you are using a hosted agent, your private NuGet repository must be publicly accessible. Otherwise you will need to run your build agent on the same network as your NuGet server.[image]

Comment: as mentioned in above comment :     
Ok, so I followed the above steps and managed to add the Telerik repo to my VSTS build definition, but upon queuing the build it still failed retrieving the telerik packages - the console states only one feed was used though: "Feeds used: api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

any ideas? I feel like I'm so close now!

Comment: Did you create a NuGet configuration file?

Comment: worked once I added the actual nuget and telerik repos to my config, thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Nuget Installer task which is deprecated now.

You can use NuGet task, detail settings as below:

[image]

Select restore command -> click New to add the credential from outside feed -> in the new window -> select basic authentication -> input feed URL, username and password -> verify the connect is successful -> Ok.

[image]

[image]

Save the build definition and queue again, now the nuget packages should be download successful by the NuGet task.

Comment: Thank you very much, the screenshots you've shown seem EXACTLY like what I'm looking for, I will try it now and get back to you!

Comment: Ok, so I followed the above steps and managed to add the Telerik repo to my VSTS build definition, but upon queuing the build it still failed retrieving the telerik packages - the console states only one feed was used though: 
 "Feeds used:    https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"